# Flash " float left < stretch > float right "

Tags: html, flash, actionscript

is there way make `swf` like this :

[image]

via AS?

Comment: make sure you've set `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE` and listen for the resize event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that what you want is to have the two fixed boxes at the sides of the screen? Use:

```
fixed1.x = 0;
fixed2.x = stage.width - 200;
```

Comment: I get it!

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResize);
fixed2.x = stage.stageWidth /2 + 200;
function onResize(e:Event):void
{
fixed2.x = stage.stageWidth /2 + 200;
}

Comment: Oh, you should have mentioned you wanted it to change when you re-sized it. Sorry, I would have mentioned the event listener.